# Android remove onClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-tablelayout

In my Android app I have a custom table where each row has an `OnClickListener` and an `OnItemLongClickListener`.

Now I would like to remove only the `OnClickListener`.
I tried this:

```
 row.setOnClickListener(null);
```

This works fine. The `OnClick` functions will not execute,
but my `OnItemLongClickListener` doesn't work anymore after I remove the `OnClickListener`. Where is my mistake?

Comment: show me where are you setting onlongclicklistener

Comment: I guess Your onItemClickListener has never worked, it was the clickListener() that consumed the click event maybe. Please show Your part of code....

Comment: i start an new post, with more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897658/android-custom-table-list-with-a-static-row

Answer (score -2):

Try this code instead:

```
//row.setOnClickListener(null);
row.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: clickable false will also disable onLongClickListener

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the actual behavior of what i suggested. It doesn't work.