# android custom table list with a static row

Tags: android, list, view

**UPDATE WITH VIEW HOLDER**

```
public class DatabaseListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<DatabaseListItems> databaseList;
    ArrayList<String> DeleteList = new ArrayList<>();

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvFirstName;
        TextView tvSecondName;
        View row;
    }



    public DatabaseListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DatabaseListItems> list) {
        this.context = context;
        databaseList = list;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return databaseList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return databaseList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final DatabaseListItems databaseListItems = databaseList.get(position);

        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_item, null);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvFirstName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewFirstName);
            viewHolder.tvSecondName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewSecondName);
            viewHolder.row = rowView.findViewById(R.id.row);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }



        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        holder.tvFirstName.setText(databaseListItems.getFirstName());
        holder.tvSecondName.setText(databaseListItems.getSecondName());




        if (databaseListItems.getFirstRow() == true) {

            holder.tvSecondName.setAlpha(0.0f);
            holder.tvFirstName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#161616"));
            holder.row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f7"));
            holder.row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent=new Intent(context,OtherActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } else {
            holder.tvSecondName.setAlpha(1.0f);
            }
        }

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

in my android app, i have got an custom table list, where the data will be dynamic filled.

only the first row should a an static row, which i set programmatically.

i have this function to fill my data into the list

```
private void showList() {

        boolean FirstRow = true;

        ArrayList<DatabaseListItems> databaseList = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseList.clear();


        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE;


        Cursor c1 = dbHandler.selectQuery(query);
            if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    DatabaseListItems databaseListItems = new DatabaseListItems();

                    if (c1.getPosition() == 0 && FirstRow == true) {

                        databaseListItems.setFirstRow(true);

                        FirstRow = false;

                        databaseListItems.setFirstName("FIRST ROW");

                        databaseListItems.setSecondName(null);

                        c1.moveToPosition(-1);

                    } else {
                        databaseListItems.setFirstRow(false);

                        FirstRow = false;

                        databaseListItems.setFirstName(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_FIRSTNAME)));

                        databaseListItems.setSecondName(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SECONDNAME)));

                        }


                    databaseList.add(databaseListItems);

                } while (c1.moveToNext());
            }
            c1.close();


        DatabaseListAdapter databaseListAdapter = new DatabaseListAdapter(getActivity(), databaseList);
        ListView.setAdapter(databaseListAdapter);


    }
```

**DatabaseListItems**

```
public class DatabaseListItems {

    String firstname;
    String secondname;
    Boolean FirstRow;



    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String first name) {
        this.firstname= firstname;
    }

    public String getSecondName() {
        return secondname;
    }

    public void setSecondName(String secondname) {
        this.secondname = secondname;
    }



    public Boolean getFirstRow() {
        return FirstRow;
    }

    public void setFirstRow(Boolean FirstRow) {
        this.FirstRow = FirstRow;
    }


}
```

**DatabaseListAdapter**

```
public class DatabaseListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<DatabaseListItems> databaseList;
    ArrayList<String> DeleteList = new ArrayList<>();




    public DatabaseListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DatabaseListItems> list) {
        this.context = context;
        databaseList = list;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return databaseList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return databaseList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final DatabaseListItems databaseListItems = databaseList.get(position);


        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_listview_item, null);

        }


        TextView tvFirstName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewFirstName);
        tvFirstName.setText(databaseListItems.getFirstName());


        TextView tvSecondName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewSecondName);
        tvSecondName.setText(databaseListItems.getSecondName());

        View row = convertView.findViewById(R.id.row);
        ImageView Arrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Arrow);






        // First Static Row
        if (databaseListItems.getFirstRow() == true) {

            tvSecondName.setAlpha(0.0f);
            Arrow.setAlpha(1.0f);

            tvFirstName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#161616"));
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7f7f7"));
            row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent=new Intent(context,OtherActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } else {

            tvSecondName.setAlpha(1.0f);
            Arrow.setAlpha(0.0f);


        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

[image]

On the first view, all looks fine.

but if i scroll down and up, random rows get the background color and the onClick function , which only the first row should get.

[image]
[image]

anyone an idea what i do wrong?

Comment: That's because a `listview` re-uses rows instead of creating new ones once you start to scroll. Use a `ViewHolder` pattern to set and retrieve tags so you can bind the proper data to the row. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: i dont do this before. can you tell me, how it works for my situation ?

Comment: sry, i forgot the magic word "please" :)

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html under header 9.4 ViewHolder Pattern, it'll help you understand far better

Comment: i tried to implement the view holder into my adapter (update in post 1) but the result / problem is the same :(